# Suppose that $x$ is a fixed nonnegative real number such that for all positive real numbers $E$ , $0\leq x\leq E$. Show that $x=0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that x is a fixed nonnegative real number such that for all positive real numbers $E$ , $0\leq x\leq E$. Show that $x=0$.

Answer (score 4):

If $x>0$, then $0<\frac{x}{2}<x$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume towards contradiction that $x>0$. Then $\frac{x}{2}$ is a positive real number. How does this contradict your assumption?